# How to remove items from an array of multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, treeview

I need some help on how to remove items from a TreeView (it's a Vue.js project), the TreeView is build based on an element like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "COMERCIALIZAÇÃO",
        "idp": "",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Pasta 1",
                "idp": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Pasta 1 2",
                        "idp": 5,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "name": "NO.FT.DRC.01.00.001.pdf",
                                "file": "pdf",
                                "idp": 6
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 8,
                                "name": "PR.FT.DRC.01.00.003.pdf",
                                "file": "pdf",
                                "idp": 6
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "name": "imprimir p luiza.pdf",
                        "file": "pdf",
                        "idp": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 66,
                        "name": "Pasta 1 3",
                        "idp": 5,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 77,
                                "name": "NO.FT.DRC.01.00.001.pdf",
                                "file": "pdf",
                                "idp": 66
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 88,
                                "name": "PR.FT.DRC.01.00.003.pdf",
                                "file": "pdf",
                                "idp": 66
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Backend.docx",
                "file": "pdf",
                "idp": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "DT.DC.RPI.03.03.1235_V2.docx",
                "file": "pdf",
                "idp": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "DISTRIBUIÇÃO",
        "idp": "",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Pasta 2",
                "idp": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "pasta 2 1",
                        "idp": 11,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 13,
                                "name": "script.sql",
                                "file": "pdf",
                                "idp": 12
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "GERAÇÃO",
        "idp": "",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Pasta 3",
                "idp": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "SERVIÇOS",
        "idp": "",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "teste",
                "idp": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm not sure, but I think that the best way to describe that element is: array of mutidimensional arrays, right?

I've created a CodePen to show the closest I got when using recursivity, but surely mine isn't the best solution since it doesn't work on every delete. Take a look at my code: https://codepen.io/luizarusso/pen/zYxLOPb?editors=1010

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id == item.id) {
        //se achou o cara que vai ser removido, chama a função de remover
        return this.removeItem(i);
    } else {
        if (items[i].children) {
            if (items[i].idp == "") {
                this.caminho = [];
            }
            this.caminho.push(i);
            this.delFile(item, items[i].children);
        } else {
            if (items.length == 1 + i) {
                this.caminho.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Feel free to optimize my code directly on CodePen if you prefer :)

EDIT: Just to clarify, my problem here is strictly on how to remove an element by the id. When the user clicks on the bin icon I know what element I need to remove, but I don't know how to take it off of the array. Map, Filter and other native JS functions cannot do that to an array of arrays/JSON, so I tought about using recursivity or something else to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with where I placed the `this.caminho.pop()`

I should only do that in the "else" of the condition that compares the id of the current item with the id of the item I'm looking for.

```
delFile(item, items) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].id == item.id) {
            //if the current item has the same id as the item I'm looking for
            //it means I found the guy and I call the function to remove it
            return this.removeItem(i);
        } else {
            //otherwise, I keep on searching
            if (items[i].children) {
                //if the item on the actual index have children, I'll search among them
                if (items[i].idp == "") {
                    //if the items doesn't have a parent, I clean the "caminho" (path) var. That var traces the route till the item I'm looking for
                    this.caminho = [];
                }
                //I push the index to the var that traces the route
                this.caminho.push(i);
                //I call the function back again, now with the child items
                this.delFile(item, items[i].children);
            }
            if (items.length == 1 + i) {
                //if the item's lenght has been completely coursed, I pop the index out of the var that holds the route, because at this point I know the item I'm looking for is not among them
                this.caminho.pop()
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Here is the solution: https://codepen.io/luizarusso/pen/zYxLOPb
Works with treeview with any deepness

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at objects, not just arrays.
Let me recommend an example library. https://github.com/leezng/vue-json-pretty.

If your question about multidimensional array iteration and process i think you have to ask on javascript and/or algorithm tags.
I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at the example library you recommended, but my problem here is strictly on how to remove an element by the id. When the user clicks on the bin icon I know what element I need to remove, but I don't know how to take it off of the array. Map, Filter and other native JS functions cannot do that to an array of arrays/JSON, so I tought about using recursivity or something else to make it work.